# How to create a constructor of a class that return a collection of instances of that class?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, collections, constructor

My program has the following class definition:

```
public sealed class Subscriber
{
    private subscription;
    public Subscriber(int id)
    {
        using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
        {
           this.subscription = dc._GetSubscription(id).SingleOrDefault();                
        }            
    }
}
```

,where

`_GetSubscription()` is a ***sproc*** which returns a value of type  `ISingleResult<_GetSubscriptionResult>`

Say, I have a list of type `List<int>` full of 1000 `id`s and I want to create a collection of subscribers of type `List<Subscriber>`.

How can I do that without calling the constructor in a loop for 1000 times?

Since I am trying to avoid switching the DataContext on/off so frequently that may stress the database.

TIA.

Comment: Where do the 1000 id's come from?
Can you alter the database so it uses a function instead of a sproc?

Comment: Thanks for your comment...
Not by choice really, I'm just coding in the way to use that funny sproc as I were told, my user name kind of giving out some hints on my power of influence to others
 :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a static factory method which calls a private constructor.

```
public sealed class Subscriber
{
    // other constructors ...

    // this constructor is not visible from outside.
    private Subscriber(DataContext dc, int id)
    {
       // this line should probably be in another method for reusability.
       this.subscription = dc._GetSubscription(id).SingleOrDefault();                
    }

    public List<Subscriber> CreateSubscribers(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
        {

           return ids
             .Select(x => new Subscriber(dc, x))
             // create a list to force execution of above constructor
             // while in the using block.
             .ToList();
        }            

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Stefan,

Your answer is really cool.  However I got a System.ObjectDisposedException as the DataContext dc is disposed.

System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled
  Message="Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'."
  Source="System.Data.Linq"
  ObjectName="DataContext accessed after Dispose."
Thanks

Comment: I tried saving a local copy of the return value but that still doesn't work.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by doing something like.....

return ids.select(x => new Subscriber(dc, x)).ToList();

But I'm confused what's going on here.  One thing that I'm pretty sure is that the IEnumerable<Subscriber>'s life time is tied with the DataContext.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I fixed it. The problem is that the lambda expression is executed when accessing the `IEnumerable` (from the caller). A common mistake when working with `IEnumerables`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan for your solution, that really helps, I know that's the so-called "deferred execution" in LINQ to SQL, but still want to know why IEnumerable is gone with the DataContext, even a reference is saved.

Comment: It's not the deferred execution of LINQ to SQL, there is not LINQ to SQL involved here. It's the problem of the `Select(x => ...)`. The lambda expression is not executed in this line of code. The lambda is a delegate, it is just a reference to a "piece of code", which is not executed yet. It will be executed in the `foreach` statement, which gets the items from the IEnumerable. Just put a breakpoint to the lambda expression (not the select, but the lambda), and see it in the debugger.